# Arranging 3 images in HTML email, without gaps

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

As you can see in the screenshot, I've got 3 rows, each containing a piece of the full image I am trying to piece together on this HTML email (Zurb Ink).

I've had all padding etc removed however this is how outlook displays it still:

[image]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9j59g602/  (looks almost fine on a browser though)

Edit and test here: https://putsmail.com/tests/1e3ab350-c1f4-4c22-a178-8372e9ec1851

The most recent change I've attempted is:

```
border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
```

To the tables and TD containing the element however it continues to revert to this. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

This is what the image and text beside it is using:

```
<table class="twelve columns hide-for-small" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td class="nopadding">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nopadding" style="padding:0px;"><img src="http://storage.pardot.com/84452/9496/book_top.jpg" alt="" title="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="eight sub-columns left-text-pad whitebg tbpadding">
        <p><strong>The guide highlights:</strong></p>
        <ul class="highlights" style="margin: 0;">
            <li>The most commonly searched for Audi models</li>
            <li>The fastest growing Audi leasing opportunities</li>
            <li>The most successful contract terms for closing Audi leasing deals</li>
        </ul>
        <span><strong>Make sure you don't miss out, <img src="http://storage.pardot.com/84452/9498/download_btn.jpg" alt="" title="" class="downloadbtn" /><br>your free and exclusive insights guide today.</strong></span>
    </td>
    <td class="four sub-columns rmpadding nolineheight" style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
        <img src="http://storage.pardot.com/84452/9492/book_cover.jpg" alt="" title="" width="214" height="194" valign="top" />
    </td>
  <td class="expander"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="nopadding">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="nopadding" style="padding:0px;"><img src="http://storage.pardot.com/84452/9490/book_bottom.jpg" alt="" title=""  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your images. It should get rid of the gaps between the images.

```
style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; display:block;"
```

Comment: No difference, same amount of space between them

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: bottom` to the top image and `vertical-align: top` to the bottom one?

Comment: Add display:block and border-collapse:collapse to the parent td of each image.